# Prevent contenteditable element from getting focus when clicking parent

Tags: html, events, focus, contenteditable

When clicking *anywhere* above the "Outside" div container in the following example, the contenteditable span element gets the focus.

```
<div style="margin:30px">
    <span contenteditable="true" style="background:#eee">
        Hello World
    </span>
    <div>Outside</div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AXM4Y/

I want the contenteditable behave more like a real text input, thus only clicking the span element itself should trigger its focus. How do I do this? How can the event capturing of the container element be stopped. I've already tried "e.stopPropagation()" with jQuery on the parent div, but it didn't work.

Comment: Doesn't happen in Firefox or IE 11 but does in Chrome. It seems to include the top and left margins in the hit zone for the contenteditable span. Seems like a WebKit/Blink/Chrome oddity. I'd suggest avoiding putting a margin on the container, if possible.

Comment: I have found a solution.
Have a look at my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30629511/1892693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with the way I put `pointer-events: none` on parent element and `pointer-events: all` on element with content editable attribute.

Comment: Since the issue is not present in the newer Chrome versions, I cannot verify your solution, but I trust you and accept the answer - in case anyone else is running into the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, I had issue on current Chrome and solve it like described yesterday.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I just tried my jsfiddle from above and it worked in Chrome 42/Windows 8.1

Comment: I tried this but with no success - could you provide a fiddle with the solution?

Comment: This did nothing to me as of Chrome 57

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit more to making a content editable behave like an input but in answer to your question, this works in Chrome 98 browser.

```js
const myEditableContainer = document.querySelector('.my-editable__container');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
let disabled = false;
const buttonText = (disabled) => `Click to ${disabled ? 'enable' : 'disable'}`;

button.innerHTML = buttonText(disabled);
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    disabled = !disabled;
  button.innerHTML = buttonText(disabled);
  myEditableContainer.classList.toggle('my-editable-container--disabled', disabled);
});
```

```css
.my-editable__container {
  position: relative;
}
 
.my-editable__cover {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: white;
}

.my-editable-container--disabled .my-editable__cover {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin:30px">
  <div class="my-editable__container">
    <span class="my-editable" contenteditable="true" style="background:#eee">
        Hello World
    </span>
    <span class="my-editable__cover"></span>  
  </div>
    
   <button>
     Enable/Disable
   </button>
  
  <div>Outside</div>
</div>
```